# Eloquent How do I store data if i have 2 models with "one-to-many" on one model?

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-design, eloquent, relational-database

Ok, i have the following ER Diagram that shows my relations in DB:
[image]
I am willing to generate a `User` when the `Order` is made. The `Order` can contain many `Products`, also the `Orders` are grouped by their `transaction_id`, so i can include all the products in the same order for a User. I am trying to save them all but i am getting `Field 'transaction_id' doesn't have a default value`. I've managed to save the user, also to link the order with the product and the user but i still can't figure out how to save transaction_id linked with order.
These are my migrations:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('transaction_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('transaction_id')->references('id')->on('transactions');
            $table->timestamps();

Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->float('price',8,2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->enum('status',['open','closed']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My models:

User Model:

```
public function orders() {return $this->hasMany(Order::class);}
```

Order Model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
        ->withPivot('quantity')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Transaction::class);
    }
```

Transaction Model:

```
public function orders() {return $this->hasMany(Order::class);}
```

This is how i'm trying to save them:

```
$user->save();
$transaction->save();
$order = new Order();
$order->user_id = $user->id;
$user->orders()->save($order);
$transaction->orders()->save($order);
$order->products()->attach($cartItem->id, ['quantity' => $cartItem->qty]);
```

P.S. Sorry for the long post, i am out of ideeas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$order = new Order();
$order->user_id = $user->id;
$order->transaction_id = $transaction->id;
$order->save();
```

Comment: This is so simple! Can't believe i missed this part. Thank you!